# How do I update ADFS SSL certificate on secondary ADFS 2.0 installed on windows server 2008 R2 using powershell

Tags: powershell, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

How do I update ADFS SSL certificate on secondary ADFS 2.0 installed on windows server 2008 R2 using PowerShell?

- Installed certificate on certificate store.
- Provided read permissions to ADFS service account on private key.
- Bind the certificate on IIS
- Restart the service

Comment: What have you tried, and what issues are you having?

Comment: Just a thought - would this work for ADFS 2.0? - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vilath/2015/09/02/how-to-update-certificates-for-ad-fs-3-0/

Comment: The other way I have used (horrible hack) is to swop the primary and secondary around. You can then run all the PS commands etc. on that box.